# Trying to understand Kendo UI Grid Editing

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui-grid

I've setup a grid with inline editing, and have the following for transport code.  (Using local data).  Why would the create event fire when I click the update button instead of the update event?

It may also help me if someone could explain what happens when the edit button is clicked in regards to what events are fired, etc.

"columnData" is a local dataset, and in reality I don't think I need the create as I don't have any functionality to add rows.  This is just a simple editable grid where a user is allowed to edit 3 out of 4 columns with the first
 column being read only.

```
transport: {
     read: function(e) {                               
        e.success(columnData);
     },
     update: function(e) {
        e.success();
     },
     create: function(e) {
        var item = e.columnData;
        item.Id = columnData.length + 1;
        e.success(item);
     }
   }
```